# How to get a single space surrounded in single quotes in courier font?

Tags: spacing, punctuation, typewriter

I've tried \texttt{' '} and \verb#' '# but those give me

[image]

when I'm really looking for the single quotes to be in code font. I can do it with double quotes like this:

[image]

but I can't get the single quotes to surround a single space. Appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{upquote} %for verbatim to use textquotesingle
\begin{document}

\texttt{" "} \texttt{\textquotesingle\ \textquotesingle} \verb#' '# 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe `\texttt{"\mbox{ }"}`?

Comment: @egreg Yes, should be considered, but imho the question is more about the "upquote".